# Getting nth item of a BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to return the data held by the nth item of a BST, I'm trying to do an inorder traversal with a counter, and when the counter is larger than n, return the current node. My current code seems to always return the first item, and I can't see where my logic is wrong. I only wrote the nth and inOrder methods, the rest were provided. I think I'm incrementing my counter too often, is that the cause or am I doing something else wrong. I'll post the main method I'm testing with below as well.

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class BST {
    private BTNode<Integer> root;

    public BST() {
        root = null;
    }


    public boolean insert(Integer i) {
        BTNode<Integer> parent = root, child = root;
        boolean goneLeft = false;

        while (child != null && i.compareTo(child.data) != 0) {
            parent = child;
            if (i.compareTo(child.data) < 0) {
                child = child.left;
                goneLeft = true;
            } else {
                child = child.right;
                goneLeft = false;
            }
        }

        if (child != null)
            return false;  // number already present
        else {
            BTNode<Integer> leaf = new BTNode<Integer>(i);
            if (parent == null) // tree was empty
                root = leaf;
            else if (goneLeft)
                parent.left = leaf;
            else
                parent.right = leaf;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public int greater(int n) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return n;
        }
    }

    int c = 0;
    public int nth(int n) throws NoSuchElementException {
        BTNode<Integer> node = null;
        if (root == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Element " + n + " not found in tree");
        }
        else {
            if (root != null){
                node = inOrder(root, n);
            }
        }
        return node.data;
    }

    public BTNode inOrder(BTNode<Integer> node, int n) {
        c++;
        while (c <= n) {
            if (node.left != null) {
                inOrder(node.left, n);
            }
            c++;
            if (node.right != null) {
                inOrder(node.right, n);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
}

class BTNode<T> {
    T data;
    BTNode<T> left, right;

    BTNode(T o) {
        data = o;
        left = right = null;
    }
}


public class bstTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BST tree = new BST();
        tree.insert(2);
        tree.insert(5);
        tree.insert(7);
        tree.insert(4);
        System.out.println(tree.nth(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: You modify a field everytime a method is called, so yes.   Incrementing too often

Comment: I don't want to increment until I'm at the leftmost item right? and then I'll want to increment every time I call the method? So I could add if node.left is null then increment c. Am I going the right way there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An invariant you should consider is that when n = sizeOfLeftSubtree + 1, then return that node. If n is less, then go left. If n is greater, then go right and reduce n by sizeOfLeftSubtree+1. Note that I map n=1 to the first element (the leftmost element).

You could trivially calculate the size of a subtree recursively, or you can store the size at every root (every node is a root of a subtree) modifying you insert method (save in a stack/queue all nodes visited and if a new node is added just increment all sizes by 1).

If the size is stored the complexity will be O(log n). If not if could become O(n^2).

```
public int nth(int n) throws NoSuchElementException {
if( sizeOfTree(this.root) < n || n < 1)
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Element " + n + " not found in tree");

BTNode<Integer> root = this.root;
boolean found = false;
do{
    int sizeOfLeftSubtree = sizeOfTree(root.left);
    if( sizeOfLeftSubtree + 1 == n ){
    found = true;
    }else if( n < sizeOfLeftSubtree+1 ){
    root = root.left;
    }else if( sizeOfLeftSubtree+1 < n ){
    root = root.right;
    n -= sizeOfLeftSubtree+1;
    }
}while( !found );

return root.data;
}

public int sizeOfTree(BTNode<Integer> root){
if( root == null )
    return 0;
else
    return sizeOfTree(root.left) + 1 + sizeOfTree(root.right);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is way more efficient than what I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

You don't change `node` in the `inOrder` method.

```
public BTNode inOrder(BTNode<Integer> node, int n) {
    c++;
    while (c <= n) {
        if (node.left != null) {
            // **** Add this - or something.
            node = inOrder(node.left, n);
        }
        c++;
        if (node.right != null) {
            // **** Add this - or something.
            node = inOrder(node.right, n);
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

Not suggesting this is the bug you are trying to fix but it is certainly a problem with the code.

Comment: This works better, but if I pass n as 1, it returns the root rather than the leftmost item. I need to increment c somewhere else...